# PIC ADC Alternate sampling

Tags: pic, adc, sampling

I'm relatively new to PIC controllers and I'm trying to figure out the best ACD operating mode for my setup.

I'm using the PIC32MX250F128B controller and I have two analog input connected to the PIC AN9 and AN10 pins.

I thought the Alternating Sample mode(with auto sample enabled) would be good for me, by connecting AN9 to the PIC's MUXA and AN10 to MUXB. I've set the number of samples per interrupt to 16, but I'm confused how my buffer will store the values. Is it "MUXA, MUXB, MUXA, MUXB..." or something else?